# In Anuglar 1.5.8 How to make check/uncheck checkbox functionality common for a website?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox

I am working on a website which has custom designed tables all over the application. All tables have a common functionality of checkbox check/uncheck.

I have used a very simple way to do this.
Creating an array of selected ids.
On toggle, check if Id exists in the array, then remove else add.
And on checkAll/uncheckAll, push all the ids in the array or empty the array.

This code is repeated in each controller of every page that has a table in it.

What I am looking for is some help/suggestion, how to make this functional by defining this code in some service/factory and can be used all over the application.

**Toggle check/uncheck**:

```
function toggle(id) {
    let index = vm.selectedIds.indexOf(id)
    if(index >= 0) {
        vm.selectedIds.splice(index, 1);
    }
    else {
        vm.selectedIds.push(id);
    }
}
```

**CheckAll/uncheckAll**:

```
function checkUncheckAll() {
    if(vm.selectedIds.length != vm.renderedList.length && vm.selectedIds.length <= vm.renderedList.length) {
        vm.selectedIds = [];
        angular.forEach(vm.renderedList,function(row){
            vm.selectedIds.push(row._id);
        });
    }
    else {
        vm.selectedIds = [];
    }
}
```

Let me know if I need to add any other details or any other code.

Thanks.

Comment: Are there multiple checkbox groups? Or is it a singular group of checkboxes which must have its state mutated?

In either case I would *strongly* recommend using a component here and not a service

Comment: these are singular group of checkboxes. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create a service with methods as you want,
like this,

```
service('myservice', myservice);
function myservice() {
this.toggleAll = function(vm.selectedIds, vm.renderedList) {
    if(vm.selectedIds.length != vm.renderedList.length && vm.selectedIds.length 
    <= vm.renderedList.length) {
        vm.selectedIds = [];
        angular.forEach(vm.renderedList,function(row){
            vm.selectedIds.push(row._id);
        });
   } else {
       vm.selectedIds = [];
   }
   };
}
```

and then inject and use the service where you need it, like this:

```
controller('myController', myController);
myController.$inject = ['myservice'];

function myController(myservice) {
var vm = this;
vm.checkAll = checkAll;
vm.selectedIds;
vm.renderedList;

checkAll = function(vm.selectedIds,vm.renderedList) {
    myservice.toggleAll(vm.selectedIds,vm.renderedList);
}
}
```

regards

Comment: Thanks i was able to do this using similar method in the service.